# Illustrator CC: no snap when drawing polygon

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, drawing

Using the polygon tool, the mouse cursor isn't able to snap to any guide or center point of existing paths and objects. The other drawing tools seem to snap correcty.

Answer (score 1):

It does snap in my CS6 copy. Make sure you have the smart guides turned on via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: They were already on because I wrote that it works with all other - except for the polygon and the star tool.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then, it works in my AI so it must be something wrong with your AI, in which case nobody could answer this. It is not a known issue for all i know.